# Tracking work hours through git

Tags: git, bash, tracking

I recently finished a project that involved me working variable hours in one sitting.

For example, I might start at 8AM and go till 2:30 PM.
I would make a commit as soon as I started, and commit right before I left.

I want to approximate how many hours I have worked on this project.

I had planned on looking through my commits and figuring this out manually, but the git web interface just gives a vague timestamp such as "authored 2 months ago".

Does anybody know of any third party app that counts hours through git?

Or hopefully provide any pointers on what to try next?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the manual approach just using `git log`?

Comment: Check out the [git time tracker](http://gitorious.org/gtt)

Comment: git time tracker won't work because I would have had to have used it from the beginning. I already finished.

Comment: I'm trying the manual approach with git log right now, but I don't trust my implementation very much so far.

Comment: Does anyone know what the -0700 means? This is copied directly from my git log.
Date:   Thu Aug 15 14:43:19 2013 -0700

Comment: To those visiting in the future: @jnaranjo's `-0700` was referring to his GMT offset (i.e. 7 hours west of GMT).

Comment: If anyone else is looking into a non-cli option, I've created [Git Timer](https://git-timer.com) App (mac only) that automatically tracks your dev time through the git status command. All you need to do is select your dev folder, hit start when starting your work. You don't actually need to commit anything, just make sure to start/stop the tracker when you stop working.

Answer (score 13):

git-hours didn't work for me. So I have built a simple npm script called [git-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-time).

Install

`npm install -g git-time`

Usage

`git-time <path>`

Where `<path>` should be a valid Git repo root path.

Comment: inspired by @vmf91 I've build a tool called [hours-report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hours-report), to use it, you need to be in the root of you git folder and run 
`npx hours-report`
works on node 12 and above

Answer (score 12):

I have created [git-hours](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/git-hours) tool to estimate the hours spent on a git repository as you described.

The algorithm to calculate the hours is quite simple and dumb. See the documentation to get an idea how it works: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/git-hours#how-it-works

For example, estimating hours spend on Bootstrap:

```
➜  bootstrap git:(master) git hours
{

  ...

  "total": {
    "hours": 9959,
    "commits": 11470
  }
}
```

*Please note that the information is not accurate enough to be used in billing. It gives a rough idea of the project's size.*

Comment: I recently made [git-csv-timesheet](https://npmjs.com/git-csv-timesheet) based on git-hours (thanks @Kimmo). If you can't get git-hours to work, want csv output or need to track multiple repositories, you could try that instead

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install git-hours -g
```

then , run :

```
cd /to/your/local/repository

git hours ; # total of all time
git hours --since yesterday # since yesterday
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I couldn't manage to build git-hours I made a tool to estimate the work done by each developer on the repository, following a similar simple algorithm: it still assumes a flat duration for the first commit of the session.

You can get it here: [git-estimate](https://github.com/luigitni/git-estimate)

The code is written in plain go and uses [go-git](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4) to read the repo's commits.

#### Usage

At a minimum run:

```
git-estimate -repo=/path/to/repo
```

this will use default settings to compute the time spent on the repo at the specified path.

```
git-estimate -h
  -baseline float
        baseline value for session estimate (default 2)
  -estimate string
        estimation method. Accepted values are "session" and "day". (default "session")
  -json
        if true will output estimates in JSON format
  -repo string
        git repository path. If no flag is specified the current folder is assumed (default ".")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also a small Python script for that: [coded4](https://github.com/Xion/coded4). Setup:

```
git clone git://github.com/Xion/coded4.git
cd coded4
./setup.py develop
```

Use:

```
cd /to/your/local/repository
coded4 .
```

And to provide a rough idea of options available:

```
coded4 -h
usage: coded4 [-h] [--repo TYPE] [--format FORMAT] [--since DATE]
              [--until DATE] [--cluster-algo ALGO] [--approx-algo ALGO]
              [--epsilon MINUTES]
              DIRECTORY
```

There are also: [git_time_extractor](https://github.com/rietta/git_time_extractor) and [a blog-post about getting time estimates using git-pandas](http://www.willmcginnis.com/2016/04/16/estimating-time-spent-project-git-pandas/).

Comment: Much faster to install than `git-hours`. And in my case `git-hours` failed to install at all.

Comment: Simpler way to install this one: `pip install coded4`

Answer (score 1):

Try https://gitential.com

Before estimating time spent with coding, Gitential deduplicates authors and filters code changes considered as outliers to reduce the noise of git data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/) Space with (at least) Git repository (Assembla's or Github's or Bitbucket's) and Time Tool (and specially formatted Git's commit message) and get *integrated by custom period* time-reports from Time Tab.

Anyway, time tracking for **every single commit** is your own task - nobody knows, how much you really work between two consecutive commits